# Kendo AutoComplete covering Grid with white box

Tags: css, kendo-grid, kendo-autocomplete

I have a Kendo Grid displaying fees, and above that I have an AutoComplete to allow the ability to search based on user. The problem with this is that the AutoComplete is covering part of the grid. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Issue]

This is the css:

```
#searchPanel {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

#searchPanel .editor-field {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#searchPanel .editor-label {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 7px;
}
```

I have tried using `position` and `z-index` to get rid of the white box but it still is showing up over the grid. It seems to be an issue with just the autocomplete box and not the label. The autocomplete box has class `.editor-field` and the label has class `.editor-label`, and they are both wrapped in the `searchPanel` div.

Comment: Please try to reproduce the problem with some example

Comment: @dev_in_progress What do you mean? What info do you need? I thought I laid it out clearly, but just left me know what you need exactly and I can update my post

Comment: A working example that shows your problem. For example, you can use https://dojo.telerik.com/ to try to reproduce your problem and provide it to us so we can work on that example and try to find a solution